# How to remove an nested JSON object using id

Tags: javascript, json

In my application I create a JavaScript object based on a JSON similar to this:

```
{
  name: "root",
  id: 112,
  children: [
    {
      name: "child one",
      id: 231,
      children: [
       {name: "grand child 1", id: 334, children: []},
       {name: "grand child 2", id: 784, children: []}
      ]
   },
   {
     name: "child two",
     id: 343,
     children: []
   }
  ]
}
```

How can I remove any Child by his id? Please note that I don’t know the static path to the node e.g id == 334 so I am wondering how I could remove that node with just knowing it's id.

Comment: How would you _find_ the record you need? Do that, but then delete it ( with, say, `Array.splice()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: please elaborate the question

Answer (score 2):

```
function del(obj,id){
  obj.children = obj.children.filter(el => {
    if(el.children) del(el,id);//delete subnodes
    return el.id !== id; //delete this
 });
}
```

A recursive approach to traverse the objects, usable as:

```
del(
 { children:[ { id:1 }, { id:2, children:[{id:1}] }] },
1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
var abc = your json object;
```

//now filter the item based on id

```
abc = jQuery.grep(
                abc.children, 
                function (item,index) { 
                  return item.id !=  "343"; 
                });
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var delIt = function (obj,id) {

   return obj.children = obj.children.filter(function (child) {
        if(child.children) delIt(child,id);
        return child.id!=id;
    });


}

var x= delIt(Tobj,335);
```

You can use filter function to collect items which are not equals to given id