# Deleting a child from a nested object structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion, data-structures

I have this data structure and trying to write a function where we can delete a specific child and all its children if we call a function with the datastructure and the child id. Here is how the data structure looks like:

```
const dataStructure = {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Parent",
  "parent_id": null,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "P",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "C",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "E",
          "parent_id": 3,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "F",
      "parent_id": 1,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

So if I call the function like `removeFromTree(dataStructure , id)` then that specific `Id` should be deleted along with its children if any. I have already written a function below that takes the `dataStructure` and the `name` as arguments which seem to work but I need to implement this with the id instead to avoid deleting multiple teams with same name. Here is what I have already written:

```
function removeFromTree(dataStructure, name) {
  if (dataStructure.name.trim() === name.trim()) {
    dataStructure = undefined;
  } else {
    dataStructure.children.forEach((child, id) => {
      if (!removeFromTree(child, name)) dataStructure.children.splice(id, 1);
    });
  }

  return dataStructure;
}
```

Any suggestions on implementing this with the id instead of name would be great, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an nested JSON object using id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300438/how-to-remove-an-nested-json-object-using-id) – the upvoted answer works as is for your use case. (though it won't remove the root node)

Comment: That worked like a charm, any idea on how to get better at this type of operations and manipulations of datastructure?